# C++ - SIGSEGV doing push_back on a vector<Mat>

Tags: android, c++, opencv, vector, mat

I'm developing an Android App and I have this problem in my native code.

These vectors are global.

```
vector<Mat> listaMatDes;
vector<Mat> listaMatKey;
vector<int> listaCols;
vector<int> listaRows;
```

I also have this function, in which descriptors and keyPoints contain the addresses of some Mats (using this function getNativeObjAddr()):

```
void rellenarObjetos(jlong* keyPoints, jlong* descriptors, jint* cols, jint* rows, int length){

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){

        listaCols.push_back(cols[i]);
        listaRows.push_back(rows[i]);

        Mat* aux_des=(Mat*)descriptors[i];
        listaMatDes.push_back(aux_des->clone());

        Mat* aux_key=(Mat*)keyPoints[i];
        listaMatKey.push_back(aux_key->clone());
    }

}
```

I've checked the two auxiliary Mat and they are created well.

I've this error **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000001 (code=1)** and it's caused by the line

```
listaMatDes.push_back(aux_des->clone());
```

but i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming the whole day makes you crazy (and silly, at least to me), I was passing from java code an array of **LOCAL** mat addresses (long[] created using the function getNativeObjAddr() which return the address in memory of the mat), so It wasn't going to work...

I solved it by creating a long array as a class field and passing this array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate `listaMatDes.push_back(aux_des->clone());` in:

```
Mat m = aux_des->clone();
listaMatDes.push_back(m);
```

This way, you can see if the error really is in the push_back, I would say it's probably in the clone.